# Unable to declare user-defined variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-5.5, aggregate, user-defined-type

I'm creating procedure called `min_max` to find minimum and maximum for every column in a table.

But I'm encountering an error for declaring the variable. See below:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS min_max //
CREATE PROCEDURE min_max ()
BEGIN
DECLARE col_name VARCHAR(64);
DECLARE col_names CURSOR FOR
SELECT column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'customer'
  ORDER BY ordinal_position;

OPEN col_names;
SET @num_rows=0;
SET @i=0;
SET @test='';

select FOUND_ROWS() into @num_rows;

the_loop: LOOP

   IF @i > @num_rows THEN
        CLOSE col_names;
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;

    FETCH col_names 
    INTO col_name;     

     SELECT CONCAT(MIN(col_name),"->",MAX(col_name)) as Min_Max_val FROM customer;

    SET @i = @i + 1;  
END LOOP the_loop;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

call min_max();
```

How should I define the variable correctly? What did I do wrong? I'm lost...

UPDATE:
The result now:

[image: <code>last_update</code> is one of the column names.]

`last_update` is one of the column names in `customer`.

Comment: *How should I define the variable correctly?* Local variables do not need in declaration. *I'm encountering an error for declaring the variable.* Where is error message? I don't see it... Why do you think that the problem is in variable declaration? I think the error is NOT FOUND (i.e. cursor is empty). Declare continue handler for NOT FOUND instead of `@i`.

Comment: @Akina I can't even compile this statement. I declared `col_name` but I'm still getting syntax error at the position I commented at. I wonder why?

Comment: Ok so when I hover at the error line it says : @col_name is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

Comment: Oops... the variable for fetching into must be procedure-scoped, not user-defined local. Add `DECLARE col_name VARCHAR(64);` immediately after `BEGIN`, before cursor declaration, and use it instead of `@col_name`.

Comment: It was interesting for me never. I simply remember (and sometimes forget, obtain error and remember again).

Comment: It solved the issue, but it seems like col_name does not capture the values in the column. Instead the result display the name of the column. eg: COLUMN: customer_id, the result is customer_id -> customer_id. Expectation is 3 -> 4. I'll update the output.

Comment: You obtain directly what you ask. The variable value in your query is treated as a variable (i.e. its value is used as a string literal), not as a field name. You must use dynamic SQL ([prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)).

Comment: I will look more into it then. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of @num_rows and @i; you can loop without counting.  There are lots of examples floating around.

You must construct the query something like

```
SET @stmt := CONCAT('SELECT "', col_name, '", ' MIN(', col_name, '), ',
                                              ' MAX(', col_name, ')',
                       ' FROM ', tbl_name');
```

The intent is to generate this (which you cannot generate in any simpler way):

```
SELECT "foo", MIN(foo), MAX(foo) FROM tbl
```

and then prepare and execute it:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
EXPECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

That will, however, give you one line per column.  There won't be any hassles with datatypes.

Another approach would be to try to build (and execute):

```
SELECT "MINs:", MIN(col1) AS "col1", MIN(col2) AS "col2", ... FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT "MAXs:", MAX(col1) AS "col1", MAX(col2) AS "col2", ... FROM tbl
```

which will string out the values across labeled columns.